# Microsoft Edge Developer Tools won't open (blank screen)

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools

This started about a week ago. The Developer Tools (F12) opens with a blank screen and then locks up the browser. The longer I leave the browser open, the more "locked up" it gets and takes longer to shut the process down. The Task Manager does not show a memory leak or runaway CPU. In fact, the longer I leave Edge's Developer Tools blank screen open, the more Edge's CPU % drops.

I'm on Win10 1909 (Build 18363.592) and no updates are available.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the MS Edge legacy browser. It is recommended to move to the new MS Edge Chromium browser.

You can download it from the link below.

[Download MS Edge Chromium browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?form=MA13DE&OCID=MA13DE)

If you have a requirement to work with the MS Edge legacy browser then I suggest you repair/ reset the browser may help to fix the issue.

You can refer to the steps below to repair/ reset the MS Edge legacy browser.

1. Click on the **Start** button and click on the **Settings** button.
2. Click on the **Apps** option.
3. Click on the **Apps & Features** option from the left sidebar.
4. Find the **Microsoft Edge browser** application from the list and click on **Advanced options**.
   [image]
5. Scroll down and click on the **Repair** button. If the issue persists then you can also try to click the **Reset** button to reset the browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This new Edge is AMAZING! It's incredibly fast, much faster than any version of Chrome I have ever used. Thank you, that fixed it (and got got rid of the recurring bug in Edge's history that's been there since the beginning).

I didn't even know the new Edge was out yet. I'd been waiting on an announcement for it but have heard nothing from Microsoft.